# Can I have Xampp and a normal Apache 2 on the same Linux server?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

Can I have Xampp and a normal Apache 2 on the same Linux server without them conflicting with one another because of a core file/s somewhere?

I know they can't run both at the same time, but my inquiry was if I started the normal Apache2, mySQL, php etc., would having Xampp installed have any bearing on websites being resolved from outside of the LAN ? The sites are not in the same place as they are in the Xampp set up.

and similary, if I started all 3 on Xampp after stopping the normal ones, would web sites be found where they are in the Xampp set up?

You may think, what on earth is he doing?

Things is, I installed Apache2, mySQL and as a newby found it hard to get phpmyadmin set up.  After days of getting conflicting help, I decided to install Xampp as they were all done at the same time.

So I can get my old head around it all and until I can get thmySQL and PHP installed properly on the normal set up, I was going to use Xampp in the meantime, thus have both in the Linux Zorin 15.2 box.

Thanks

oz

Comment: You _really_ don't want XAMPP on linux. Every linux has this stuff built in. But, you can totally run multiple webservers as long as they run on different ports, or not at the same time. I would not bother with PHPMyAdmin, there's far better tools that don't need to run on PHP.

Comment: you could amke it work, both running at the same time, on different ports, **but** xampp is **notoriously unsecure**

Comment: Reiterating here because it's important: XAMPP is primarily for Windows machines, and specifically for development. It's not something you deploy on a server, especially not a Linux server where installing this stuff is not even hard. On Windows it can be frustrating to an extreme which is why XAMPP exists. On Linux you have `apt` and `dnf` and such which work very well.

Comment: If you're having trouble getting this set up on Linux you need to find a better installation guide for your distribution.

Comment: The reason why phpMyadmin is because I have a few sites that are Opencart the store which requires php. Other than that I wouldn't need it. I will try and get it set up again. Last time was a nightmare. Not sure why now though.